# C/C++ - convert 32-bit floating-point value to 24-bit normalized fixed-point value?

Tags: c, floating-point, normalization, fixed-point, floating-point-conversion

Please let me know how to convert 32 bit float to 24 bit normalized value? What I tried is (units * (1 <<24) but doesn't seem to be working. Please help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by '24 bit normalized value' ?

Comment: 24 bit normalized unsigned integer

Comment: So you assume that your float contains an integer ? What is your expected answer if `f=3.14159265359` ?

Comment: Isn't the internal representation of a float an implementation detail that is not specified by the standard?

Comment: @Jim No ! It's perfectly specified by IEEE see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008

Comment: I know most compilers use IEEE754, but is that guaranteed by the standard?

Comment: I believe the question is about the old trick of converting from floating-point to integer by adding a larger bias to a smaller integer to "fix" the exponent into place, then mask out the bits from the raw binary representation. Oh, and 2^24 is the largest representable integer before a 32-bit IEE754 float starts to lose precision

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is not working, (1 << 24) is too large for a 24-bit number capable of representing **0** to store, by exactly **1**. To put this another way, `1 << 24` is actually a ***25-bit*** number.

Consider `(units * ((1 << 24) - 1))` instead.

<sub>`(1 << 24) - 1` is the largest value an unsigned 24-bit integer that begins at **0** can represent.</sub>

Now, a floating-point number in the range [**0.0** - **1.0**] will actually fit into an unsigned 24-bit fixed-point integer without overflow.

Answer (score 0):

A normalized fixed-point representation, means that the maximum representable value, not strictly reachable, is 1. So 1 is represented by `1<<24`. See also [Q Formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_%28number_format%29).
For example Q24 means 24 fractional bits, 0 integer bit and no sign. If using a 32 bits unsigned integer to manage a Q24, the remainig 8 bits can be used to ease calculations.
Before translating from floating-point to fixed-point representation, you always have to define the range for your original value. Example: the floating point value is a physical value in the range from `[0, 5)`, so 0 is included and 5 is not included in the range, and your fixed-point value is normalized to 5.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

float length_flp = 4.5;     // Units: meters. Range: [0,5)
float time_flp = 1.2;       // Seconds. Range: [0,2)
float speed_flp = 1.2;      // m/sec. Range: [0,2.5)
unsigned uint32_t length_fixp;   // Meters. Representation: Q24 = 24 bit normalized to MAX_LENGTH=5
unsigned uint32_t time_fixp;     // Seconds. Representation: Q24 = 24 bit normalized to MAX_TIME=2
unsigned uint32_t speed_fixp;    // m/sec. Repr: Q24 = 24 bit normalized to MAX_SPEED=(MAX_LENGTH/MAX_TIME)=2.5

void main(void)
{
    printf("length_flp=%f m\n", length_flp);
    printf("time_flp=%f sec\n", time_flp);
    printf("speed_flp=%f m/sec\n\n", length_flp / time_flp);

    length_fixp = (length_flp / 5) * (1 << 24);
    time_fixp = (time_flp / 2) * (1 << 24);
    speed_fixp = (length_fixp / (time_fixp >> 12)) << 12;

    printf("length_fixp=%d m\n", length_fixp);
    printf("time_fixp=%d sec\n", time_fixp);
    printf("speed_fixp = %d msec [fixed-point] = %f msec\n", speed_fixp, (float)speed_fixp / (1 << 24) * 2.5);
}
```

The advantage with normalized representation is that operations between normalized values return a normalized value.
By the way, you have to define a generic function for each operation (division, multiplication, etc.), to prevent overflow and save precision.
As you can see I've used a small trick to calculate `speed_fixp`.
The output is

```
length_flp=4.500000 m
time_flp=1.200000 sec
speed_flp=3.750000 m/sec

length_fixp = 15099494 m [fixed-point]
time_fixp = 10066330 sec [fixed-point]
speed_fixp = 25169920 msec [fixed-point] = 3.750610 msec
```

Comment: The `x * (1 << 24)` is redundant, it can be just `(x) << 24`.  There is also ambiguity of whether this is a 8:24 or 40:24 format, or possibly even overflow on 16-bit embedded systems.  Should use a specific type such as `uint32_t` or `uint64_t` and explicitly elucidate (semantic `typedef uint32_t uint_fixed_8_24_t`) which format a particular variable uses *before normalization* or expensive conversion to double/float.  (See also: [doom m_fixed.c](http://doomwiki.org/wiki/Doom_source_code_files), which is barely adequate by today's coding stds)  Btw be careful: C defaults to ints & doubles.

Comment: Can not use `x<<24` because of the floating-point left operand. I've added more details about the fixed-point type, though the question is clearly talking about a 24 bit normalized value. You are absolutely right about the usage of platform independant types.